# Proper way to have initial properties for users in Firebase [with react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I want to build an application where the users could login with Github (as of now, and probably Facebook, Google+ in the future).

I'm wondering how could I have initial properties when the user logs in first time, which would be modified in the future?

In my App component I have an `onAuthStateChanged` function which will push the users info into the database, but the issue is (obviously) that it will do this every time:

```
    firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({
                user
            });

            usersRef.push({
                id: user.uid,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                coins: 3000
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                user: undefined
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there a way I could check if the user logged in before? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Hi Florin, have you read about High Order Components?

Comment: `.onAuthStateChanged` is how to properly do it. This method does not push anything anywhere.

Comment: @RonRoyston, could you give me a little hint please?

Comment: `.onAuthStateChanged` is asynchronous and if you notice even when you are logged in (via whatever oAuth provider or email) your page might blink on refresh from being logged out to being logged in. In other words, `console.log` `.currentUser.email` or something and notice how it fires twice on a page refresh, once with `null` and then (if you are logged in) with `billy@foo.com`. So, use that method to drive the state of your app. Hope that helps. I don't use react but this vanilla js example may help https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a Firebase Authentication Trigger as documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events.

You could set up a trigger that runs once on the Firebase servers just after a user is created; that trigger can update data in the database for the user, which could include defaulting certain values.  Your React app would then be able to read that data when it needs it.